# Stretch items elements height in a Flexbox nav with fixed height

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a navigation, with fixed height, that use the flexbox layout module. It have two items (ul elements) where in one I want that its `li` tags take all the height of the nav and the other one I want that its `li` tags behave normally. I tought that assigning `display:block` to the `li` tags that I want they take all the height of the nav would work, but it behaves as a `display:inline-block`.

```css
nav {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    background-color: #000;
    height: 65px;
}

nav ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding-left: 0;
}

nav ul li {
  float: left;
}

nav ul.item1 li {
  display: block;
  background-color: red;
}

nav ul.item2 li {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul class="item1">
    <li>#1</li>
    <li>#2</li>
    <li>#3</li>
  </ul>
  <ul class="item2">
    <li>#4</li>
    <li>#5</li>
    <li>#6</li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer is to use nested flexbox.

1. Remove `align-items: center;` from `nav`, so that flex items can stretch (default behavior) to the same height as the container.
2. Reset the margin by adding `ul { margin: 0; }`, so that no top and bottom margins.
3. Remove all the `float` and `inline-block`, you don't need it in flexbox layout.
4. Apply `display: flex;` to all - `nav`, `ul`, and `li`.
5. Finally add `align-items: center;` to the `li` to center the text vertically.

```css
nav {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  background-color: black;
  height: 65px;
}

nav ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  display: flex;
}

nav li {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

nav ul.item1 li {
  background-color: red;
}

nav ul.item2 li {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul class="item1">
    <li>#1</li>
    <li>#2</li>
    <li>#3</li>
  </ul>
  <ul class="item2">
    <li>#4</li>
    <li>#5</li>
    <li>#6</li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

#### Update

Modified version for just the left side fully stretches to height, and the right side behaves as inline elements.

```css
nav {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  background-color: black;
  height: 65px;
}

nav ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  display: flex;
}

nav li {
  display: flex;
}

nav ul.item1 li {
  align-items: center;
  background-color: red;
}

nav ul.item2 {
  align-items: center;
}

nav ul.item2 li {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul class="item1">
    <li>#1</li>
    <li>#2</li>
    <li>#3</li>
  </ul>
  <ul class="item2">
    <li>#4</li>
    <li>#5</li>
    <li>#6</li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, seems logical as solution, but how can I do that just the left side is full stretched as height and the right side behaves as inline elements?

Answer (score 1):

Just add `height: 100%` to both the `ul` and `li`.

```css
nav {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    background-color: #000;
    height: 65px;
}

nav ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding-left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

nav ul li {
  float: left;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

nav ul.item1 li {
  background-color: red;
  height: 100%;
}

nav ul.item2 li {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul class="item1">
    <li>#1</li>
    <li>#2</li>
    <li>#3</li>
  </ul>
  <ul class="item2">
    <li>#4</li>
    <li>#5</li>
    <li>#6</li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: But in this manner you lose the center alignment of texts. I want that just the background of the `li` tags of item1 are stretched, with the text still vertically aligned

Comment: @Keaire Then it means you want the `li` to be a flexbox, not the `nav`. Or have the background on the `ul`.

Comment: See my updated answer, I made both `ul` and `li` flex boxes.

Comment: Seems that it's working but I think that there is a more clean solution instead of using so many properties.